# Angular2 dynamic form with remote metadata

Tags: forms, angular, dynamic, metadata, angular2-forms

I created a dynamic form following the instructions in the [angular cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html) and then I've tried to create the form with metadata that I have in my database.

I made an HTTP request to the get field types, names, ids, etc. but when I try to build the form as in the angular example, nothing happens or I get errors on console.

Here's the code from the tutorial:

```
export class AppComponent { 
    questions: any[]; 
    constructor(service: QuestionService) { 
        this.questions =  service.getQuestions(); 
    } 
}
```

And this is what I did:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  campos: any[] = [];
  constructor(private servico: FormDadosService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.servico.getCampos().subscribe(this.processaCampos);
  }
  processaCampos(dados) {
    for (let i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
      this.campos.push(new CampoBase({
        nome: dados[i].ZI2_NOME,
        label: dados[i].ZI2_DESC,
        ordem: dados[i].ZI2_ORDEM,
        obrigatorio: dados[i].ZI2_OBRIGAT,
        tamanho: dados[i].ZI2_TAM,
        valor: '',
        tipoCampo: dados[i].ZI2_TIPO
      }))
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> `error_handler.js:50EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

I think I need to know a way to render the form after all data about it has arrived from my HTTP request.

Comment: What errors do you get? Can you include the relevant part of your code?

Comment: google did:
export class AppComponent {
  questions: any[];
  constructor(service: QuestionService) {
    this.questions = service.getQuestions();
  }
}

Comment: and I did:
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  campos:any[]=[];
  constructor(private servico: FormDadosService) {}
  ngOnInit() {    this.servico.getCampos().subscribe(this.processaCampos);
}
  processaCampos(dados) {
   for (let i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
    this.campos.push(
      new CampoBase({
        nome: dados[i].ZI2_NOME,
        label: dados[i].ZI2_DESC,
        ordem: dados[i].ZI2_ORDEM,
        obrigatorio: dados[i].ZI2_OBRIGAT,
        tamanho: dados[i].ZI2_TAM,
        valor: '',
        tipoCampo: dados[i].ZI2_TIPO
    })
   )
  }    
 }
}

Comment: I am getting this error:
error_handler.js:50EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work this way:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  campos: any[] = [];

  constructor(private servico: FormDadosService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.servico.getCampos().subscribe((data) => {
      data.forEach(campo => {
        this.campos.push(new CampoBase({
          valor:     '',
          nome:      campo.ZI2_CAMPO,
          label:     campo.ZI2_DESC,
          tipoCampo: campo.ZI2_TIPO,
          tamanho:   campo.ZI2_TAM
        }))
      });
    });
  }
}
```

This question can be marked as solved.

Thanks everyone.